# awakeFromFetch with non-managed property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an NSManagedObject subclass with some image data in an NSData property (`imageData`), which is automatically persisted. After loading the data from the network I also set a custom NSImage property (`image`) with an image created from the data.

The problem is that if the object is a fault, `awakeFromFetch` is **not** called when I access the `image` property, since it is not handled by Core Data. I can of course override the `image` accessor and make sure the properties are loaded (by accessing `imageData`) but it would be nice if there was a way to have `awakeFromFetch` invoked as normal. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to expand this question a bit as it's a bit unclear. `awakeFromFetch` will not be called on fault just because you access an attribute. It is called whenever you fetch with `fetchAsFaults` set to NO.

Comment: @TechZen: From what I can see, `awakeFromFetch` is invoked whenever I access, for example, the `imageData` property. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @TechZen: And what is `fetchAsFaults`?

Comment: Sorry, going off the top of my head, it is `returnsObjectsAsFaults` in NSFetchRequest. `awakeFromFetch` should be called when the objected is fetched. Simply accessing an attribute shouldn't trigger it. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: @TechZen: Thanks, `setReturnsObjectsAsFaults` works. It's still not ideal. I'd like the fault to fire when I access my derived (image) property, but not sure what the cleanest way is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per TechZen's suggestion, I now execute the fetch request with `returnsObjectsAsFaults` set to `NO`. It's of course not ideal to pull all data from the cache each time the object is fetched, but in my case I always use the data immediately so it's acceptable.

Comment: If I understand your design correctly, you would get better performance by not loading the UIImage until the `image` attribute is accessed. Put the the code for loading the image into a custom `image` attribute accessor. That will make sure the image is always available but will prevent you from having images in memory you don't actually need.

Comment: @TechZen: I can do that (although in practical terms it will make little difference), but that requires that the object is **not** a fault when the `image` attribute is accessed, because once in the accessor, it seems I can't fire the fault anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to do two contradictory things, you want the main entity to remain fault but be able to access its attributes. You cannot do that. A fault by definition has not attributes/properties because it is just a placeholder in the object graph. If you want your main object to remain a fault, you should move the UIImage to its own entity and link it to the main object.  You should then be able to walk the object graph to obtain the UIImage without triggering the loading of the main object's fault placeholder.

Comment: Well, not really. But I wanted to use `awakeFromFetch` to create the image from the data, and from everything I've understood that's just what `awakeFromFetch` is supposed to be for. But accessing that attribute (which is only exists in the class, not the entity) doesn't fire the fault. I need it to fire, because without the imageData I can't create the derived image.